# Future deletion of Deprecated Network Connectivity Methods in Android SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, compatibility, deprecation-warning

I'm working on an Android SDK that uses network connectivity functionalities. In the SDK, I currently have a method isNetworkAvailable() which checks for network connectivity. This method uses both the modern NetworkCapabilities API and the deprecated ConnectivityManager API for compatibility across Android versions.

```
    private fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {

        var isAvailable = false

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)

            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    isAvailable = true
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    isAvailable = true
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                    isAvailable = true
                }
            }
        } else {
            val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected) {
                if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    isAvailable = true
                } else if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    isAvailable = true
                }
            }
        }

        return isAvailable;
    }
```

Will the users of the SDK have compilation issues if the deprecated methods get completely removed in the future?

What are the implications should the deprecated methods get completely deleted in the future? And is there a better way to handle compatibility across different API versions?